# AWS CLI: cannot restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time with "--serverless-v2-scaling-configuration"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

```
John@MacBook-Pro:~/IWG/code$ aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time \
--restore-type full-copy  \ 
--source-db-cluster-identifier mySourceCluster  \
--db-cluster-identifier  myTargetCluster \
--restore-to-time  2022-09-01T08:00:00Z \
--vpc-security-group-ids sg-07102f7235a9363d3 sg-3bd3ce7f \
--port 5432 \
--db-subnet-group-name default-vpc-5321e635 \
--no-enable-iam-database-authentication \
--serverless-v2-scaling-configuration MinCapacity=1.0,MaxCapacity=4.0

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --serverless-v2-scaling-configuration, MinCapacity=1.0,MaxCapacity=4.0

John@MacBook-Pro:~/IWG/code$
```

What on earth is going on here?  What do they mean by

```
Unknown options: --serverless-v2-scaling-configuration, MinCapacity=1.0,MaxCapacity=4.0
```

This is exactly what the AWS Official Doc is advising us to do:

```
--serverless-v2-scaling-configuration MinCapacity=1.0,MaxCapacity=4.0
```

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time.html

> --serverless-v2-scaling-configuration (structure)
>
> Contains the scaling configuration of an Aurora Serverless v2 DB
> cluster.
>
> For more information, see Using Amazon Aurora Serverless v2 in the
> Amazon Aurora User Guide .
>
> MinCapacity -> (double)
>
> The minimum number of Aurora capacity units (ACUs) for a DB instance
> in an Aurora Serverless v2 cluster. You can specify ACU values in
> half-step increments, such as 8, 8.5, 9, and so on. The smallest value
> that you can use is 0.5.
>
> MaxCapacity -> (double)
>
> The maximum number of Aurora capacity units (ACUs) for a DB instance
> in an Aurora Serverless v2 cluster. You can specify ACU values in
> half-step increments, such as 40, 40.5, 41, and so on. The largest
> value that you can use is 128.
>
> Shorthand Syntax:
>
> MinCapacity=double,MaxCapacity=double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to do with AWS CLI Version.
It used to be:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.4.7 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

after updating it to:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.29 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

I no longer see the error.